# Powershell regex \d+

Tags: regex, powershell

I have this short code:

```
$text1 = "Telefon-: +49 1234 567890"
$pat 1 = "Telefon.*(?<tel>\d+)"
$text 1 -match $pat1
$matches.tel
```

As result I only got the last digit. Why? I thought \d+ would take 567890.
I hope somebody can me explain this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `.*` match?

Comment: You should play a little bit with it to learn how it works ... [regex101  Telefon.*(?<tel>\d+)](https://regex101.com/r/jpZ71K/1)

Comment: .* matches -: +49 1234 56789

Comment: .* is greedy and matches everything it can only leaving /d+ to consume the last digit

Comment: You might look for a certain number of digits at the end of the string or you might look for digits at the end of the string following a white space.  ;-)

Comment: OK, now I understand!
Thank to all for helping :)